# Querying with SQL Server for SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012

I am developing a SSRS report and need help with the dataset queries. I am not sure how to write the query to achieve the desired data.

Query1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FullDate,
  SUM([Gross]) AS Gross
  ,StoreName

FROM [T1] inner join [T2]
on T1.StoreKey = T2.StoreKey

inner join T3
on T1.DateKey = T3.DateKey

where [Store] = 'B'
and FullDate = '2016-10-24'

group by FullDate,
StoreName
```

The result for this is:

```
 FullDate     Gross      StoreName
2016-10-24   2621.89          B
```

Query2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FullDate,SUM(TotalCost) AS TotalCost,
  SUM([Gross]) AS Gross
  ,StoreName

FROM [T1] inner join [T2]
on T1.StoreKey = T2.Storekey

inner join T3
on T1.DateKey = T3.DateKey

inner join T4
on T1.DateKey = T4.DateKey
and T1.StoreKey = T4.StoreKey


where [Store] = 'B'
and FullDate = '2016-10-24'

group by FullDate,
StoreName
```

The result for this is:

```
FullDate      TotalCost     Gross        StoreName
2016-10-24       5         20060.12         B
```

I want to achieve 2621.89 with query2 so that I can use it in one table for SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. I took the TotalCost column query separately in Left Join

```
    SELECT DISTINCT FullDate SUM([Gross]) AS Gross
        ,StoreName
        ,SUBSET.TotalCost
    FROM [T1]
    INNER JOIN [T2] ON T1.StoreKey = T2.Storekey
    INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.DateKey = T3.DateKey
    INNER JOIN T4 ON T1.DateKey = T4.DateKey
        AND T1.StoreKey = T4.StoreKey
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT FullDate SUM(TotalCost) AS TotalCost
            ,
            ,StoreName
        FROM [T1]
        INNER JOIN [T2] ON T1.StoreKey = T2.Storekey
        INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.DateKey = T3.DateKey
        INNER JOIN T4 ON T1.DateKey = T4.DateKey
            AND T1.StoreKey = T4.StoreKey
        WHERE [Store] = 'B'
            AND FullDate = '2016-10-24'
        GROUP BY FullDate
            ,StoreName
        ) AS SUBSET ON FullDate = SUBSET.FullDate
        AND [Store] = SUBSET.FullDate
    WHERE [Store] = 'B'
        AND FullDate = '2016-10-24'
    GROUP BY FullDate
        ,StoreName
        ,SUBSET.TotalCost
        ,
    SELECT DISTINCT FullDate SUM([Gross]) AS Gross
        ,StoreName
        ,SUBSET.TotalCost
    FROM [T1]
    INNER JOIN [T2] ON T1.StoreKey = T2.Storekey
    INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.DateKey = T3.DateKey
    INNER JOIN T4 ON T1.DateKey = T4.DateKey
        AND T1.StoreKey = T4.StoreKey
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT FullDate SUM(TotalCost) AS TotalCost
            ,
            ,StoreName
        FROM [T1]
        INNER JOIN [T2] ON T1.StoreKey = T2.Storekey
        INNER JOIN T3 ON T1.DateKey = T3.DateKey
        INNER JOIN T4 ON T1.DateKey = T4.DateKey
            AND T1.StoreKey = T4.StoreKey
        WHERE [Store] = 'B'
            AND FullDate = '2016-10-24'
        GROUP BY FullDate
            ,StoreName
        ) AS SUBSET ON FullDate = SUBSET.FullDate
        AND [Store] = SUBSET.FullDate
    WHERE [Store] = 'B'
        AND FullDate = '2016-10-24'
    GROUP BY FullDate
        ,StoreName
        ,SUBSET.TotalCost
        ,
```